# SSL endpoint not responding -> secure.eu-de.bluemix.net

Tags: ibm-cloud

According to Bluemix Doc this -> `secure.eu-de.bluemix.net` -> is the regional endpoint for public Bluemix in Germany - however it seems not to  responding.

Comment: could you please be more specific when you say it is not responding? I just pinged it and it works fine.

Comment: `ping secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net
PING eu-gb.custom-domain.bluemix.net (5.10.124.142): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 5.10.124.142: icmp_seq=0 ttl=174 time=105.330 ms
64 bytes from 5.10.124.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=174 time=106.057 ms
64 bytes from 5.10.124.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=174 time=104.466 ms`

Comment: `ping` works for me as well (in UK, no association with Bluemix). @AlexdaSilva Although `https://secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net/` in a browser says it can't be reached (`ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT`) ... but I've no idea whether it's meant to do more (I'm not a user of Bluemix).

Comment: this is only used for Bluemix customers to configure their application CNAME when they want secure custom domains. Trying to reach it directly with https does not work.

Comment: You are pointing the uk endpoint. try secure.eu-de.bluemix.net it don't respond

Comment: @AlexdaSilva. I just pinged secure.eu-de.bluemix.net and I just received timeout errors myself. Note that it is the Frankfurt version and not London...

Comment: Pinging secure.eu-de.bluemix.net was successful for me today.